# How to check if a delegate responds to a selector?

Tags: selector

I would like to check if this delegate is able to respond to this selector before calling it.

```
[self.delegate cellMove:self];
```

Comment: `if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(cellDidSelectMove:)])` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please try this

```
- (void)userPressedMoveButton:(id)sender {
        if (self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(cellDidSelectMove:)) {
            [self.delegate cellDidSelectMove:self];
            [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
        }
    }
```